# Oracle - Another way for month query?

Tags: performance, oracle

first... sorry for my english.

I have a query like this:

```
Select *
From tableA
Where (
          TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(dateA(+),'SYYYY'))  =  2013
          AND  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(dateA(+),'MM'))  =  02
          AND  to_number(to_char(dateA(+),'dd'))  <=  25
          )
```

and retrieve me the data from each date until last number that I give as parameter, in this case the day 25. This working but delay very much because the form of "Where" statement... anybody know another way that retrieve the data so fast and with the same functionality?

Comment: Why not a simple `where date between <start> and <end>` ?

Comment: Because the client only want select one date u.u

Comment: This may be a gray area, but I think working code which requires tweaking is a better fit for the Code Review site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableA
 WHERE dateA BETWEEN trunc( date '2013-02-26', 'MM' ) AND date '2013-02-26'
```

This will return all the rows where `dateA` is between the first of the month and the specified date.  If there is an index on `dateA`, Oracle would be able to use it for this sort of query (though whether it actually would is a separate issue).

Comment: This will also return an extra day if the data is stored without time component.

Comment: Yeah, this it's I wanna do!! Thank you very much, Justin Cave n__n